# Small questions about NIST database software

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, notation, physical-chemistry, evaporation

I am using NIST Standard Database software, which can give us many physical properties for many materials. (PS: I obtained a trial version from the net, so the *help* is unavailable.)

There are my three small questions:

**1.** I need the surface tension gradient $d\sigma/dT$ for some common fluid, such as water. However, I can not find an option to add it from the four tabs under *properties* menu. Please see the following figures;

**2.** What is the meaning of the $K$ value in the first figure?

**3.** Is there any method to calculate a user-defined function, for example,
$$\frac{d\rho_\text{v}^\text{s}}{dT}
=\rho_\text{v}^\text{s}(p_\text{s},T)\left[\frac{\tilde{L}}
{p_\text{s}T\Delta V_\text{specific}}-\frac{1}{T}\right],$$
where $\rho_\text{v}^\text{s}$ is the saturated density corresponding to $p_\text{s}$ and $T$, $\tilde{L}$ is the latent heat of unit mass, $\Delta V_\text{specific}$ is the specific volume change associated with vaporization.

I am also very happy to exchange experiences with anybody who has any experience on the NIST Database software :) Thanks for your help!

[image: fig.1]
[image: fig.2]
[image: fig.3]
[image: fig.4]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a specific software, not physics.

Comment: @ ACuriousMind Hi, could you please suggest where is a proper place to post my question? Actually, it is a database [link](https://www.nist.gov/srd/refprop) which is  extensively by researchers in physics and chemistry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of an SE site where this question would be on-topic (which doesn't mean there isn't one).